# Qlikview sorting date dimension formatted as text

Tags: sorting, qlikview

Can someone help me sort a date dimension in a QlikView pivot? The dimension is set as follows:
`Week(DateField) & chr(13) & '' & Weekstart(DateField,0,-1)`

An example of value:

```
"43 
10/19/2014"
```

Another example:

```
"1
12/28/2014"
```

chr(13) returns a new line so that the week number and the day with which the week starts are placed on two different rows.

I have tried putting this expression in a listbox to play with it and to try different variants for sorting. Below are my attempts:

Sort by expression: `=DateField`

Sort by expression: `=LEFT(DAY(DateField) + NUM(MONTH(DateField))*100 + YEAR(DateField)*10000,100)`

Sort by expression: `=LEFT(DateField,2)` (not ok anyway as it would not work if multiple years were loaded)
etc

but nothing seems to work

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you said, the issue is that when you create that concatenation, it becomes a string and it's sorted as such.

Luckly, QlikView has the Dual function that can help you in this case, defining the dimension as a calculated dimension with the following expression :

```
=Dual(Week(DateField) & chr(13) & '' & Weekstart(DateField,0,-1), Weekstart(DateField,0,-1))
```

The syntax of Dual is Dual(Text, Numeric Value), meaning that it will create an object that will be represented by the value Text but sorted by the Numeric Value.

Check QlikView help page for this function for further information.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

=Weekstart(DataField,0,-1)